# Minio deployment using kubernetes doesn't work as expected

Tags: kubernetes, minio, k3s

I'm experimenting with kubernetes and a minio deployment. I have a k3s 4 node cluster, each one with 4 50GB disk. Following the instructions [here](https://docs.min.io/minio/k8s/tenant-management/deploy-minio-tenant-using-commandline.html) I have done this:

1. First I installed [krew](https://krew.sigs.k8s.io/docs/user-guide/setup/install/) in order to install the [minio](https://docs.min.io/minio/k8s/deployment/deploy-minio-operator.html#deploy-operator-kubernetes) and the [directpv](https://github.com/minio/directpv/blob/master/README.md) operators.
2. I installed those two without a problem.
3. I formatted every **Available** hdd in the node using `kubectl directpv drives format --drives /dev/vd{b...e} --nodes k3s{1...4}`
4. I then proceed to make the deployment, first I create the namespace with `kubectl create namespace minio-tenant-1`, and then I actually create the tenant with:

   `kubectl minio tenant create minio-tenant-1 --servers 4 --volumes 8 --capacity 10Gi --storage-class direct-csi-min-io --namespace minio-tenant-1`
5. The only thing I need to do then is expose the port to access, which I do with: `kubectl port-forward service/minio 443:443` (I'm guessing it should be a better way to achieve this, as the last command isn't apparently permanent, maybe using a LoadBalancer or NodePort type services in the kubernetes cluster).

So far so good, but I'm facing some problems:

- When I try to create an alias to the server using [mc](https://docs.min.io/docs/minio-client-complete-guide.html) the prompt answer me back with:

> mc:  Unable to initialize new alias from the provided
> credentials. Get
> "https://127.0.0.1/probe-bucket-sign-9aplsepjlq65/?location=": x509:
> cannot validate certificate for 127.0.0.1 because it doesn't contain
> any IP SANs

I can surpass this with simply adding the `--insecure` option, but I don't know why it throws me this error, I guess is something how k3s manage the TLS auto-signed certificates.

- Once created the alias (I named it test) of the server with the `--insecure` option I try to create a bucket, but the server always answer me back with:

  `mc mb test/hello`

  `mc: <ERROR> Unable to make bucket \test/hello. The specified bucket does not exist.`

So... I can't really use it... Any help will be appreciated, I need to know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Kubernetes provides it's own CA which is trusted internally, but without further configuration they will not validate on your own machine. Are you sure your alias is working properly? Check other commands using the alias to be sure they are working such as `mc ls test`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guided by information at the [Minio documentation](https://docs.min.io/docs/how-to-secure-access-to-minio-server-with-tls.html). You have to generate a public certificate. First of all generate a private key use command:

```
certtool.exe --generate-privkey --outfile NameOfKey.key
```

After that create a file called `cert.cnf` with content below:

```
# X.509 Certificate options
#
# DN options

# The organization of the subject.
organization = "Example Inc."

# The organizational unit of the subject.
#unit = "sleeping dept."

# The state of the certificate owner.
state = "Example"

# The country of the subject. Two letter code.
country = "EX"

# The common name of the certificate owner.
cn = "Sally Certowner"

# In how many days, counting from today, this certificate will expire.
expiration_days = 365

# X.509 v3 extensions

# DNS name(s) of the server
dns_name = "localhost"

# (Optional) Server IP address
ip_address = "127.0.0.1"

# Whether this certificate will be used for a TLS server
tls_www_server
```

Run `certtool.exe` and specify the configuration file to generate a certificate:

```
certtool.exe --generate-self-signed --load-privkey NameOfKey.key --template cert.cnf --outfile public.crt
```

And the end put the public certificate into:

```
~/.minio/certs/CAs/
```